# How add FutureBuilder correctly flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm starter in Flutter . I would like to add FutureBuilder correctly calls the function _getAlert() in this piece of code . How I can do that ?

```
class _AlerteState extends State<Alerte> {
  final List<Notifs> notifs = NotifsList.getNotifs();
  Widget _buildNotifsList() {
    return Container(
      child: notifs.length > 0
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: notifs.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Dismissible(
                  onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                    setState(() {
                      notifs.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                  secondaryBackground: Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Delete',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  background: Container(),
                  child: NotifsCard(notif: notifs[index]),
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                );
              },
            )
          : Center(child: Text('No Items')),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        minimum: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 20.0, right: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 10.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF6F7F8),
          body: _buildNotifsList(),
        )));
  }
}
```

So, How to use FutureBuilder to build ListTile ?

Please help.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is some piece of code I think this will work for you

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: notifs ,  /// YOUR RESPONSE VARIABLE WHICH IS OF TYPE FUTURE
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text(
                    "Connection State is none",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  );

                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              height: height * 0.2,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );

                case ConnectionState.active:
                  // Fethed some data some data to be fetched
                  return Text(
                    "Fetching Data from Server",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  );

                case ConnectionState.done:
                  // Task  of Future Builder is done now
                  // checking the data received is not null. If not null show the data in UI

                  return snapshot.data != null
                      ? _buildNotifsList(snapshot.data) 
: /// SOME ILLUSTRATION FOR NO DATA AVAILABLE
```